# Need a good method for troubleshooting javascript in a complicated situation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been tasked with figuring out why a jquery slider won't function. I know it was working shortly after install because I browser checked it. The only reasonable conclusion I can come up with is that there is a JavaScript library conflicting as they are calling WAY too many in the header.

I have no control over removing JS calls from the header as this is in a overly complicated extremely limiting CMS...

Does anyone know of a good way to troubleshoot JavaScript conflicts using firebug, or any other tools/methods? I can't just remove them in the firebug live HTML editor as it would require a page reload correct?

**Here's the error from Google Chrome ***

```
Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/html.
Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type text/plain.
11:02:44 (0ms): global: Logger output to the function console.log() has been enabled.
frame: [object HTMLIFrameElement]
frame: [object HTMLIFrameElement]
frame: [object HTMLIFrameElement]
```

Unfortunately this doesn't mean much to me yet.

Comment: Well the first thing to do is use Firebug to see whether any errors are reported. As you say, it could be anything. Thus until you can report back on specifics, all you can hope for here is vague advice (which may be what you're after :-)

Comment: Google Chrome has JavaScript Console which will show you any client side exception linking to the source code causing it. Good enough for start.

Comment: The only other tool I know of, except of firebug, is web developer (also addon for firefox)

Comment: Comments won't let me format the text well so I've updated the original Post. Thanks everyone for your help/advice.

Comment: @BMS most times you can safely ignore those warnings about MIME type interpretations (transferred as this; interpreted as that). What you're looking for are any of the notes marked with a red circle and an X, not the yellow warnings. The total number will be listed down on the bottom right when you bring up dev tools. It should give you a stack trace if there's any actual unhandled JS exception.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the advice. I don't think there are any errors, Just warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd copy the markup, add a base tag to handle relative links and start deconstructing the mess to find the culprit (using the normal array of debugging tools).

Comment: This is the method that solved the issue. I just linked to the scripts externally, and used just the slider markup. Don't know why I didn't think of this in the first place. I just found out the client switched the template since I had the JS working and didn't notify me of the changes. The new template was calling a few different versions of jquery and a few different script libraries
. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: The bigger issue is that the CMS won't let me remove them. I'm writing the CMS developers now. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: The simplest solutions hide in the darkest corners of the brain :). Good luck with that CMS.